# C++ delegation pattern explanation

Tags: c++, class, oop, namespaces, using

I need some help understanding the technical details of the following code whose aim is to delegate to the back-end, and also why it ultimately won't compile in VS but works fine in the UNIX command line:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Tree.h"
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SymTab : public Tree<T>
{
    using Tree<T> ::Insert;
    using Tree<T> ::Lookup;
    using Tree<T> ::Remove;
    using Tree<T> ::Write;
    using Tree<T> ::Set_Debug_On;
    using Tree<T> ::Set_Debug_Off;
};
```

I know that the code is somehow using namespaces, but  I never actually declared any in any of the `Tree` files. Moreover, for constructing, am I correct to assume that since no constructor is present in the `SymTab` class, it automatically calls the constructor of the super class?

Finally, this code compiles under UNIX, but in VS it gives the following errors:

```
SymTab<MyClass>::[function name]: cannot access private member declared in class 'SymTab<MyClass>'
```

Yet everything seems to be public. What gives?

Comment: "Yet everything seems to be public" -- `class`es default to private access (as opposed to `struct`s)

Comment: `using Tree<T>::Insert;` has nothing to do with namespaces. It just instructs the compiler to make `Insert` visible. By default, when using template bases, you need to use `this->function_in_template_base()` to refer to member functions in the base template class, since name lookup is deferred.

Comment: @TristanBrindle if I prefix the `using` statements with `public`, then I get linker errors: `unresolved external symbol`